# Open Server открывает localhost вместо нужного сайта

Tags: wordpress, openserver, localhost

Переношу сайт (назовём его site.com) на WP из одного локального хранилища на другое. Поместил папку с сайтом в папку OpenServer\OSPanel\domains, где расположены предыдущие проекты. Запускаю Open Server. Ввожу в адресной строке браузера http://site.com. И тут происходит то, что мне не надо - открывается страница http://localhost/ . Пробую открывать свои предыдущие проекты, расположенные в папке domains - происходит всё то же, открывается localhost.

Если это важно, то вот так выглядят настройки сервера. Например, когда-то менял порт HTTP на 83.

[image]

**Что нужно поменять в настройках Open Server или ещё чего-то, чтобы я мог попасть на site.com?**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Мб проблема в базе.
Быстрый фикс - В таблице `wp_options` в ключах `site_url` `home_url` поменять на http://localhost/

Но по хорошему - зайти в админку ( должно пустить ), установить WP DB Migrate и поменять старый url&path на новый

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом

-Клик правой кнопкой на флажок

-Настройки

- Вкладка домены

  Управление доменами
  выбрать - Ручное управление
  Имя домена вписать localhost
  Папка домена, выбрать папку с локальным сайтом

  Нажать кнопку Добавить

  Нажать Сохранить, сервер перезапустится

В браузере пишем localhost, и получаем локальную версию сайта, а не web версию.